# PHP embed html image as a link

Tags: php

How do I go about using an image as a link in php? I have never put two html elements together in one echo so it's kinda new for me. 
Here's my code:

htmltest.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<?
   require("includes/conn.php"); //link to the database
?>
<html> 
<title>HTML with PHP</title>
<body>

<?php
      echo  "<a  href="pageone.php"><img src="homelogo.jpg"  /></a>";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

That's my code. I get the following error:

PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in /home6/dreamsm2/public_html/htmltest.php on line 11

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: echo "a <href=\"pageone.php\">....  I highly suggest you revisit learning PHP.  You must escape double quotes within a double quoted string.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change the line to:

```
echo  '<a href="pageone.php"><img src="homelogo.jpg"  /></a>';
```

OR

```
echo  "<a href=\"pageone.php\"><img src=\"homelogo.jpg\"  /></a>";
```

The problem, as the error somewhat suggests, is that the PHP interpreter can't figure out where your string is supposed to start and end.  Using `\"` escapes the quotes.  Using `'` around the string gives a unique string delimiter around the string, so you are free to use double quotes inside.

Note, if you needed both single and double:

```
echo  '<a href="pageone.php" title="Andy\'s Link"><img src="homelogo.jpg"  /></a>';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `'` instead of `"` for strings, e.g.

This works: `echo '"Hello!"'; => "Hello!"`

This wont work: `echo "'Hello'";`

Comment: `echo "'Hello'";` won't work?  Really... why do you say that?

Comment: because `'` takes precedence over `"`, in my system atleast

Comment: Takes precedence?  What error do you get?  What version of PHP do you run?  What `system` are you on?

Answer (score 0):

SIMPLY DO THIS:

```
echo '<a href="page.php"><img src="Downloads_clip_image010.jpg" /></a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

For WordPress

```
<div class="floatLeft"> 
    <a href="http://trophydevelopers.com">
        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/powered-by.png">
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: 'code'<div class="floatLeft"><a href="http://trophydevelopers.com"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/powered-by.png"></a></div>