# Is it possible to store a clickable image in PHP MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql

when it will fetched/retrieved,the image is also clickable,linking towards a .php file.What is the syntax of this?
I'm working on a movie booking/cinema project,when the admin will add a new movie with a thumbnail,the user can click the image once it has been retrieved from the db.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP embed html image as a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10152099/php-embed-html-image-as-a-link)

Comment: Clickability is a construct of the presentation layer. One would normally store an image in a file server and the path to the image (and any anchors) in the database. An introductory book or tutorial on MySQL and PHP may prove useful.

Answer (score 1):

you will store the URL to the image and then when you display the image you will make the img-element the link.

something like this:

the URL that u save and retrieve from your database: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/y1U1Eqfdg7w/maxresdefault.jpg

Then you will add that to the src of an img-tag of the HTML page you are showing.
That can be done in various ways depending on your front-end engine.

```
<img src="YOUR URL" />
```

eg.

```
<a href="https://www.horse.com/">
    <!-- The link-tag is encapsulating the img tag -->
    <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/y1U1Eqfdg7w/maxresdefault.jpg" />
</>
```

For example if you are using laravel blades you would most likely send a variable to the view something like:

```
$imageURL = https://i.ytimg.com/vi/y1U1Eqfdg7w/maxresdefault.jpg
```

and on the blade:

```
<a href="##Desired end path here">
    <img src="{{ $imageURL }}" /> 
</a>
```