# Getting an image to appear in an echo <a href=

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to change the link text in this line to be an image :

```
echo "<a href='$pdf_link' target='_blank'>Click For Detailed Product PDF</a>";
```

i.e. a png instead of "Click for Detailed Product PDF"

I've tried to use this as a guide but it gets stuck on the `$pdf_link`.

[PHP embed html image as a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10152099/php-embed-html-image-as-a-link)

```
echo "<a href='$pdf_link' target='_blank'><img src="https://1234.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/pdf.png"</a>";
```

The page won't compile and this is the error;

> syntax error, unexpected '$pdf_link' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ';'
>   plus some other errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to change with:

```
echo "<a href='{$pdf_link}' target='_blank'><img src='https://1234.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/pdf.png' /></a>";
```

I have changed the double-quotes with quotes.
The `img` tag was also not closed.

edit:
you also can use backslashes for escape double-quotes:

```
echo "<a href='{$pdf_link}' target='_blank'><img src=\"https://1234.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/pdf.png\" /></a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is you're closing the string where you're echoing your output. There are a few ways of fixing this, but I think you'd be better served by not echoing out HTML like that. I'm assuming you're in a template of some description, so you're best to enter PHP parsing when you need to, and otherwise write your HTML outside of that. For example;

```
?>

<a href='<?= $pdf_link ?>' target='_blank'>
   <img src="https://1234.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/pdf.png">
</a>

<?php
```

You see I entered PHP parsing with `<?=` (the `=` meaning echo the next statement) and exited with `?>`, which allows you to use HTML outside of PHP parsing and without having to escape quotes and things like that.